# Value of an angular directive is being set twice

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm writing an Angular application that implements component approach (a-la Angular2-style). But I faced with a strange problem: when directive have to be set once, it somehow is being set twice. For a numbers in example it does not causes troubles, but for two-way binding with object it does.

There is a code:

**Module init**

```
angular.module('myModule', []);
```

**Parent directive**

```
var ParentController = (() => {
  function ParentController() {
    this._increasableValue = 1;
  }

  ParentController.prototype.update = function() {
    this._increasableValue += 1;
  }

  Object.defineProperty(ParentController.prototype, "increasableValue", {
    get: function() {
      return this._increasableValue;
    },
    enumerable: true,
    configurable: true
  });

  return ParentController;
})()

angular
  .module('myModule')
  .controller('parentController', ParentController)
  .directive('parentDirective', () => {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {},
      controller: 'parentController',
      controllerAs: 'ctrl',
      template: `
<div class="container">
        <child-directive inc="{{ctrl.increasableValue}}"></child-directive>
</div>
<button ng-click="ctrl.update()">Update</button>`
    }
  });
```

**Child directive**

```
var ChildController = (() => {
  function ChildController() {}

  Object.defineProperty(ChildController.prototype, "increasableValue", {
    get: function() {
      return this._increasableValue;
    },
    set: function(value) {
      this._increasableValue = value;
      console.log(this._increasableValue); // prints twice
    },
    enumerable: true,
    configurable: true
  });

  return ChildController;
})();

angular
  .module('myModule')
  .controller('childController', ChildController)
  .directive('childDirective', () => {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        increasableValue: '@inc'
      },
      bindToController: true,
      controller: 'childController',
      controllerAs: 'ctrl',
      template: `
<div class="container">
    <div>{{ctrl.increasableValue}}</div>
</div>`
    }
  });
```

**bootstrapping**

```
angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('wrapper'), ['myModule'])
```

**index.html (part)**

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <parent-directive>Loading...</parent-directive>
</div>
```

Why does it happen and what I can do to remove the second call?

Working example: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lodin/f6gmn1gj/2/).